# 2 variables = 1 other variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to know if we can simplify a code in Python:

```
a = 5
b = a
c = a
d = a 
...
```

Comment: `a = b = c = d = 5`?

Comment: `a=b=c=d=5`? Are you looking for this? Not sure if I understood the question properly.

Comment: Be aware that this code will copy the reference to 5, not 5 as a value.

Comment: @Justlearnedit That should not make any difference when working with immutable types like integers though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can simplify your example is by using chained assignment.

```
a = b = c = d = 5
```